# Redis Pub Sub directly use with frontend without using websocket,

Tags: websocket, redis, socket.io, frontend, publish-subscribe

Can frontend directly subscribe to redis pub sub for getting messages. Most of the blogs in internet says client has to interact with backend using web socket and web socket service will communicate with redis. Can frontend directly subscribe with redis an get the updates without using web sockets.

We are trying to make a dashboard on which graphs refreshes to show correct metrics real time. Will that work or this design has any cons?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We are trying to make a dashboard on which graphs refreshes to show correct metrics real time. Will that work or this design has any cons?

Comment: how did this go? I'm considering that option as well

Answer (score 0):

The browser (the frontend) is stateless by nature (HTTP is stateless). The instance of the (Javascript) code that "subscribes" to something effectively goes away after a page reloads. Web Sockets give you a persistent full-duplex communication channel between the browser and the server.
Before Web Sockets (and Server-Sent Events), you had to poll the server, a.k.a. check for messages for your instance/user/etc. in a loop that eats up a lot of CPU cycles. So, yes, you need Web Sockets or SSE to do async messaging efficiently on a browser.